# What upper limit to use for sandwich theorem with limit of $(7x^2y^2)/(x^2 + 2y^4)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am instructed to calculate the limit of the following using the sandwich theorem:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{7x^2y^2}{x^2 + 2y^4}$$

I understand that since all terms are positive, the lower limit is:

$$ 0 \le \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{7x^2y^2}{x^2 + 2y^4} \le (here?)$$

I have not been able to work out what to put on the right side though.

I have considered what could be added to the numerator to make it factor out nicely but have found no solution.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $y^4\geq0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $$\frac{7x^2y^2}{x^2+2y^4} \leq \frac{7x^2y^2}{x^2} = 7y^2$$ Then take limits.

Comment: oh man. So simple!! Thanks